# Retornar amount Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc, asp.net-core

Tenho um model com `category`, `Deposit`, `Date`, `Amount`, eu preciso que o `Amount` some todos os `deposit` que existem no banco de dados e retorne no `View`, eu fiz o seguinte, só que não resolveu.

```
public async Task<ViewResult> Amount()
{
    var movements = _context.Movement.Include(x => x.Deposit).ToList();

    var total = movements.Sum(x => x.Amount);
    ViewData["amount"] = total;
    return View(total);
}
```

Estou passando na View o seguinte parâmetro:

```
@ViewData["amount"]
```

Comment: Adiciona o código da sua View para a gente saber como você está tentando acessar essa informação.

Comment: @TallesSantana Olá, modifiquei.

Comment: Você ta passando o amount duas vezes para a view. Tanto no Model dela quanto no ViewData. ViewData acho que precisa de cast então arrobaViewData["amount"] as Int32 pode funcionar.

Outra opção é não usar ViewData e sim o model. Para isso, na primeira linha da sua view adicione arrobamodel int
Onde quiser usar o valor use arrobamodel ou arrobaModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta adicionar um `+` antes do `=` para que ele faça o incremento.

```
var total += movements.Sum(x => x.Amount);
```